# Android eclipse keyboard problem

Tags: eclipse, android, tablet

Not sure if I should ask this question here or somewhere else, but I am having a recurring problem. Every time I deploy my android application to my tablet in eclipse (Run As Android Application), my laptop keyboard and trackpad stops working. This is only fixable with a restart.

I am running OSX 10.6.7 with eclipse 3.6.2 and Android Development tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have [trackball mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) enabled. You can toggle trackball mode with F6.

Comment: Nope, doesn't make a difference. Even the Caps Lock light doesn't turn on, it's as though the keyboard and mouse have been completely unplugged.